# Pytest HTML Not Displaying Image

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, screenshot, pytest-html

I am trying to generate a self contained html report using pytest-html and selenium. I have been trying to imbedded screenshots into the report but they are not being displayed.
[image: Example]

My conftest.py looks like this

```
@pytest.fixture()
def chrome_driver_init(request, path_to_chrome):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=path_to_chrome)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    page_object_init(request, driver)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


# Hook that takes a screenshot of the web browser for failed tests and adds it to the HTML report
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == "call":
        feature_request = item.funcargs['request']
        driver = feature_request.getfixturevalue('chrome_driver_init')
        nodeid = item.nodeid
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = f'{nodeid}_{datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M")}.png'.replace("/", "_").replace("::", "_").replace(".py", "")
            driver.save_screenshot("./reports/screenshots/"+file_name)
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image("/screenshots/"+file_name))
        report.extra = extra
```

I am convinced the problem is with the path to the image, and I have tried so many str combinations, os.path and pathlib but nothing has worked. The screenshot is being saved in the expected location and I can open it like any other image. Its just not displaying on the report.

```
<div class="image"><img src="data:image/png;base64,screenshots\scr_tests_test_example_TestExample_test_fail_example_2022-01-18_16_26.png"/></div>
```

EDIT: For addional clairification. I have tried to use absolute path in the `extra.append`  but it kept giving me a `Cant Resolve File` error in the HTML file. My absoulte path was(with some personal details redacted) `C:\Users\c.Me\OneDrive - Me\Documents\GitHub\project\build\reports\screenshots\filename.png` I have tried it with both '/' and '\'

Also my File structure

```
project
├───build
│   ├───reports
│       ├───screenshots
│           ├───filename.png
|       ├───report.html
|   ├───run.py # I am running the test suite from here
├───scr
|   ├───settings.py
│   ├───tests
│       ├───confest.py
```

run.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system(f"pytest --no-header -v ../scr/tests/ --html=./reports/Test_Report_{today}.html --self-contained-html")
```

For Prophet, may be bless me this day
To get the `Cannot Resolve Directory` error my code is the following

```
file_name = f'{nodeid}_{datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M")}.png'.replace("/", "_").replace("::", "_").replace(".py", "")
img_path = os.path.join(REPORT_PATH, 'screenshots', file_name)
driver.save_screenshot(img_path)
extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(img_path))
```

The variable `REPORT_PATH` is imported from the settings.py (see directory tree above) and is created by

```
PROJ_PATH = Path(__file__).parent.parent
REPORT_PATH = PROJ_PATH.joinpath("build\reports")
```

also fun fact if I do `img_path.replace("\\", "/")` the error changes to `Cannot Resolve File`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have learned so much in this painful journey. Mostly I have learned I am an idiot. The problem was that I wanted to make a self contained HTML. Pytest-html does not work as expected with adding images to a self contained report. Before you can you have to convert the image into its text base64 version first. So the answers to all my owes was a single line of code.

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == "call":
        feature_request = item.funcargs['request']
        driver = feature_request.getfixturevalue('chrome_driver_init')
        nodeid = item.nodeid
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = f'{nodeid}_{datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M")}.png'.replace("/", "_").replace("::", "_").replace(".py", "")
            img_path = os.path.join(REPORT_PATH, "screenshots", file_name)
            driver.save_screenshot(img_path)
            screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64() # the hero
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(screenshot, ''))
        report.extra = extra
```

Thank you Prophet for guiding on this pilgrimage. Now I must rest.

Comment: You are not an idiot, you learned by yourself very meaningful things. What really matters here is that you made efforts, tried, learned and finally find the solution. This is what making us engineers. Not only some amount of knowledges, Google knows much more, you know, but an ability to learn new things, to find solutions.

Comment: feature_request.getfixturevalue('chrome_driver_init') -> Where does feature_request come from? I'm trying to replicate something similar.

Comment: @JustinFuruness he defined chrome_driver_init as a pytest fixture in conftest.py

Also, I think this fix (converting the screenshot to base64 before attaching as an extra) is necessary even if you're not generating a --self-contained-html report; I was getting encoding errors even without that flag.

Comment: another so [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805707/1518100) says *the standard behaviour of pytest-html is that even if you pass the image as base64 string, it will still store a file in the assets directory.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure how it works with PyTest, however we have similar issue with Java Extent Manager.
There you have to pass the absolute path of the image file, not the relative path.
As I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory) the current working directory can be achieved as following:

```py
import pathlib
pathlib.Path().resolve()
```

So, if I understand that correctly you should change your code from

```py
extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image("/screenshots/"+file_name))
```

to

```py
working_root = pathlib.Path().resolve()
extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(working_root + "/screenshots/"+file_name))
```

**UPD**
I think you are missing a `reports` subfolder here.
Instead of

```py
working_root = pathlib.Path().resolve()
extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(working_root + "/screenshots/"+file_name))
```

Try using

```py
working_root = pathlib.Path().resolve()
extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(working_root + "/reports/screenshots/"+file_name))
```

Comment: I tried using absolute paths and kept getting `can't resolve directory` errors

Comment: What is the absolute directory expression you sending to the `extra.append`? Can you share it and validate it is correct?

Comment: Added it to the original question

Comment: I'm not sure I see it there

Comment: Sorry edits are done now @Prophet

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: class Path does not define __add__ so '+' does nothing. `working_root.stem` turns it into a usable str. Still this didnt work. Added one more detail to the question I thought might be useful

Comment: OK. In your first comment here you wrote me you see the `can't resolve directory` error. Can you show me what is the actual expression you passing to the method what causing this error? I see what the correct absolute path should be. The question what is the actual path is?

Comment: added it to bottom of question. its a bit of a mess